# How can i get the specific matched fields values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have created one table below the table code.

use organization

```
db.test.insert({ bookname : "Mongodb", author : "Alex", price : 45, qty : 100})

db.test.insert({ bookname : "Cassandra", author : "John", price : 75, qty : 75})
```

Now I need the MongoDb and alex values when the book name is Mongodb

here we matched the bookname only remaining author name will display automaically?

Comment: `db.test.find({ bookname: "mongodb" })`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet using the above query it shows the entire row. but i need only bookname and author only

Comment: `db.test.find({ bookname: "mongodb" }, { bookname: 1, author: 1 })`

Answer (score 0):

What you looking is find with projection

Like this

```
db.test.find({ bookname: "mongodb" }, { _id: 0, bookname: 1, author: 1 })
```

Mongodb docs
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Answer (score 0):

To get one or more documents, you use -

```
db.test.find(<match>, <projection>)
```

where  is the filtering part (where clause in SQL), and  specifies the keys(columns in SQL tables) to return in results.

To filter the results on some field, use -

```
db.test.find({ "bookname" : "Mongodb" })
```

The above command will result all authors matching `bookname` as `Mongodb`. `{ "bookname" : "Mongodb" }` is your `match` part of the command. You can modify your the `find()` command similar to -

```
db.test.find({ "bookname" : "Mongodb" }, {"bookname": 1, author: 1})
```

The output documents of this command will have `bookname`, `author` and `_id` as keys. `{"bookname": 1, author: 1}` is your `projection` part of command. For each key we want in output we set to `1` and `0` for those we don't want.

By default all keys will be in output. If you have set any key for `1` then only that key and `_id` will be returned. If you do not want `_id` then set it to `0` in projection.

```
db.test.find({ "bookname" : "Mongodb" }, {"bookname": 1, author: 1, _id: 0})
```